# Angular 2+ Unit Test - fixture.detectChanges() removes component properties

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have this test. In there i setup some values of my component. These values determine the status of a button. Right before fixture.detectChanges() those values are still set. But after (right at const createButton....) those values are gone and set to null again.
Question is why and how can i set these values so that i am able to detect changes to the Button status.

```
it('should activate the create button with a customer and service set', () => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);

    fixture.componentInstance.entry.service = new Service('1', 'Name', null);
    fixture.componentInstance.entry.customer = customerMock;

    fixture.detectChanges();

    const createButton = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('p-button[name="createButton"]'));
    const actual = createButton.attributes['ng-reflect-disabled']; // TODO try find better way
    expect(actual).toBe('false');

  });
```

EDIT: As request. I cannot post the whole component, but I think the relevant part of the component is onInit.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.servicePoolSubscription = this.stateService.getServiceSubject()
        .subscribe(serviceList => this.services = serviceList);
      this.Entry = EntryService.prepare();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.serviceSubscription) {
      this.serviceSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
```

As i think about it. EntryService.prepare() prepares a new object. Does fixture.detectChanges trigger the onInit again?

Comment: Can you show us the code of your component you are testing ?

Comment: Have added some code @maxsoulard

Comment: it's just the first detectChanges() that triggers ngOnInit()

Comment: Ok... that could be the reason, as this is the only detectChanges i have @NormundsKalnberzins. But subsequent detectChanges won't be recognized i read somewhere

Comment: if your component state (properties) changes, subsequent detectChanges() will update UI accordingly

Comment: U did it! I inserted a detectChanges before so it wont trigger the ngOnInit after i changed the values! @NormundsKalnberzins

Comment: @NormundsKalnberzins add an answer so i can accept it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the first `fixture.detectChanges()` triggers `ngOnInit()`. Call it first time before you change the component properties.

Comment: this saved my day! thanks!
how did you know about? is it documented somewhere?